# AutoLayout resize view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have custom `UIView` with 2 multiline labels. Sometimes I need to hide this view so I set `hidden = YES` and height constraint to 0.

I am doing it this way but I'm not quite sure if I can change my constraints in my custom `UIViews'` `layoutSubviews`.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    if (!self.hidden) {
        self.heightConstraint.constant = 15 + self.titleLabel.frame.size.height + 4 + self.bodyLabel.frame.size.height + 15;
    } else {
        self.heightConstraint.constant = 0;
    }
}
```

I know that layout is not one-way street process and `layoutSubviews` can cause `updateConstraints` and vice versa.

Is it safe to change constraints of view itself in `layoutSubviews`?

Comment: You could just override the views setHidden: method and do it there. layoutSubviews is not a good place for that your right.

Answer (score 1):

`layoutSubviews` is called after the `updateConstraints` method has done its job. If you change constraints after that, you're gonna have to call `[super layoutSubviews]` again. The correct place to modify constraints is in the `updateConstraints` method, but in your case you can simply make your changes outside the `layoutSubviews` method and then call `setNeedsLayout` after you're done.

Answer (score -1):

You need `setNeedsLayout` method. Example:

```
self.view.setNeedsLayout()
```